# nextjs how to add versioning or timestamp in asset js and css url

Tags: next.js

We are facing the cache issue after each deployment in nextJs.

Because after each deployment it need a hard refresh to view the page.

So is there a way to append build version or timestamp in asset urls like js and css of index file ?

eg: /_app.js?ts=167103307790

Answer (score 0):

To append a build version or timestamp to your asset URLs in Next.js and solve the cache issue, follow these:

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  // Other Next.js configurations...

  env: {
    BUILD_TIMESTAMP: new Date().getTime(),
  },
};
```

In your component where you include styles or scripts, access the build timestamp and append it to your asset URLs:

```
// Example in a React component
const buildTimestamp = process.env.BUILD_TIMESTAMP;

// ...

<link rel="stylesheet" href={`/path/to/your/style.css?ts=${buildTimestamp}`} />
<script src={`/path/to/your/script.js?ts=${buildTimestamp}`} />
```

Comment: thanks for comments, actually i have mistake in my question. I was looking to add timestamp in static css and js . eg: <link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/6e20e7d64872d2afd9c7.css?ts=1212212">

Comment: it's okey or For JavaScript, you can do the same thing:
<script src="/_next/static/js/6e20e7d64872d2afd9c7.js?ts=<%= new Date().getTime() %>"

Comment: but how  i can bring that ?ts=877878. Because this js and links are generating automatically. So is there a way in nextjs to add the same ?

Comment: Create a next.config.js file in the root directory of your Next.js project if it doesn't already exist.